# reverse of a string

Tags: iphone, ipad

i want a program to display the reverse of a string. my program should have two textViews and a button. the string entered by user in a textView should be taken when we press the button and the reverse of that string should be displayed in the other textView. all the ib stuff to be done on window itself.

plz help me with code.
forgive me if you feel the question is simple or basic.

Comment: At least try _something_, then ask for help when what you have tried fails to work. If you don't even know where to start, ask your teacher to go over the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you read in the values from the textview into an array then reverse the array, something like this where array1 is a list of values from your textview

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int x=[array1 count] - 1;x>=0; x--){
  [tmp addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:x]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
-(NSString *) revertString:(NSString*)stringToRevert
{
    NSMutableString *reversedStr;
    int len = [stringToRevert length];

    reversedStr = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:len];     

    while (len > 0)
      [reversedStr appendString:
           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [stringToRevert characterAtIndex:--len]]];   

    return reversedStr;
}
```